# Modifying Anonymous Structs and Unions in Clang's AST

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm attempting to write an external Clang AST modifier that translates anonymous struct and union definitions to a different form.  For example, I have:

```
typedef struct test_case_t {
  struct {
    int value;
  } first[1];
  int second;
  int third[1];
} test_case_t;
```

I would like to transform this to:

```
struct test_case_t {
    struct first{
        int value;
    };
    struct first first[1];
    int second;
    int third[1];
};
typedef struct test_case_t test_case_t;
```

However, the transform seems to drop the `struct first` declaration, so this is what I get instead:

```
struct test_case_t {
    struct{ // this should be "struct first"
        int value;
    };
    struct first first[1];
    int second;
    int third[1];
};
typedef struct test_case_t test_case_t;
```

How do I go about modifying the struct definition in place and add the `first` declaration name?  I have the `RecordDecl` of the first variable definition, but I can't seem to figure out how to transform the struct definition.

Comment: it would help people to understand and answer if you show your "external Clang AST modifier" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, this is a rather interesting idiosyncrasy of Clang's AST.  When representing nested sets of structs and unions, the nested declarations and definitions are split into unique `FieldDecls`.  The struct declaration is lexically parsed first then the variable definition is parsed.  This requires that you save off a reference to the struct/union declaration and match it downstream to subsequent variable definitions.  This process can be rather tricky, but mimics the following.  Specifically, we're looking for struct declarations that match are not `isFreeStanding()`

```
for(RecordDecl::decl_iterator iter = RD->decls_begin(), end =
RD->decls_end(); iter != end; ++iter) {
  Decl *StructDecl = nullptr;
  if(FieldDecl *FD = dyn_cast_or_null<FieldDecl>(*iter)) {
    // create new FD
    if(const ElaboratedType * NET =
       dyn_cast<ElaboratedType>(SemaRef.Context.getBaseElementType(NewFD->getType())))
{
    if( StructDecl ){
      RecordDecl *MyDecl = dyn_cast<RecordDecl>(StructDecl);
      if( MyDecl )
          MyDecl->setDeclName(FD->getDeclName());
      }
     }
   }
  }else if(TagDecl *TD = dyn_cast<TagDecl>(*iter)){
     if(TD->isThisDeclarationADefinition() && !TD->isFreeStanding()){
       // save StructDecl
     }
  }
}
```